# how to save a variable from for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I want to classify my variables and save the output, but the "test" is null.
how can I fix the problem?

```
x<-sample(10)
npz<-function(x)
{
  for(x in x)
if (x < 0) {
  print("Negative number")
} else if (x > 0) {
  print("Positive number")
} else
  print("Zero")
}
test<-npz(x)
test
```

Comment: Using x twice in the loop is a bad idea, use a different index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a function for this, just inline everything with `ifelse`, which is already vectorized:

```
x <- sample(10)
test <- ifelse(x < 0, "Negative number",
            ifelse(x > 0, "Positive number", "Zero"))
```

Comment: @林家鳴 Look into using `case_when` from the `dplyr` package.  But, the question you did ask only has three classes.

Answer (score 0):

`sign` will return `-1`, `0` and `1` for negative  numbers, zero and positive numbers respectively. We can use it to index the character vector accordingly.

```
npz <- function(x) {
   c("Negative number", "Zero", "Positive Number")[sign(x) + 2]
}

test <- npz(c(-1, 2, 3, 0))
test
#[1] "Negative number" "Positive Number" "Positive Number" "Zero"
```